# Match strings which are in few elements in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on WYSWIG editor and I have option which search strings and highlight them. I used a lot of external libraries and no one find string which is in few elements, like this: (I am trying to select "Text")

```
<b>T</b>
<u>e</u>
<s>x</s>
<b>t</b>
```

or

```
<b>Te</b>
<i>xt</i>
```

How can I select string which is in few elements, using JavaScript and/or JQuery?
Thanks  for help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of doing so would be to get the `text` property of the div that contains such formatted text. In the snippet below, I have created a dummy `div` that contains the formatted HTML. So, in order to get the plain text content of the div, you can access the text property and then search within it.

Perhaps, you could also replace the newline characters using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function if required.

```js
var string = `<b>T</b>
<u>e</u>
<s>x</s>
<b>t</b>`;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = string;
console.log(div.innerText);
```